# How to filter row in SQL based on column value

Tags: sql-server

I´m making a SQL query (SQL Server Managmenet Studio) that results in an address list. A party can have two types of addresses:

- Physical address
- Correspondence address

I want the query to the following. If the party has a correspondence address then only this address should be selected, else (i.e. no correspondence address) it should select the row with the physical address. The result is that for every party only one address should be selected.

The query that I have now contains a lot of joins because the parties have roles on loans but can be oversimplified to this:

```
SELECT Party.Name, Address.AddressLine 
FROM Party
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address on (Party.AddressID = Address.ObjID)
```

The table Address contains a column UsageID with values 1 and 2 for PhysicalAddress and CorrespondenceAddress respectively.

How would I achieve this goal? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `row_number()`:

```
select * 
from (
    select p.Name, a.AddressLine, 
           row_number() over (partition by p.name order by a.usageid desc) rn
    from Party p 
        left join Address a on p.AddressID = a.ObjID
) t
where rn = 1
```

If any addresses exist, this will return the first ordered by the `usageid desc`, which should return the `CorrespondenceAddress` first if it exists.

- [Online Demo](http://rextester.com/ZJADO47139)

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! Didn't know this function until now but one to remember for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,

```
create table #party(id int identity(1,1), pAddr int, cAddr int)

create table #addr (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(1))

insert into #party(pAddr,cAddr) values (3,null), (1,1),(2,8),(3,3),(4,null),(4,5)

insert into #addr(name) values ('a'),('e'),('d'),('g')



select p.id
, case when p.cAddr is not null then p.cAddr   -- Here, checking whether,
  else p.pAddr                                 -- the corresponding address is null or not. 
  end Addresses
, name
 from #party p
join #addr a
on p.id = a.id
```

Reverting is appreciate, if query needs any updates...!!